# Transformation of variables in function in mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, functions, polynomials, variable-definitions, variable

How do i change variables of function in mathematica ? for example of 
    f(p,q) = p^3 + q^3, from p,q to x= p-q and y = p+q, so that the function now becomes f(x,y) ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) to find the old variables in terms of the new variables, and then feed the results to [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) in order to make the substitution.

```
changeOfVariables = 
 First@Solve[{x == p - q, y == p + q}, {p, q}]
(* {p -> (x + y)/2, q -> 1/2 (-x + y)} *)

f[p_, q_] := p^3 + q^3

f[p, q] /. changeOfVariables
(* 1/8 (-x + y)^3 + 1/8 (x + y)^3 *)

Simplify@%
(* 1/4 (3 x^2 y + y^3) *)
```

You can make a new function that takes `x` and `y` as inputs, like

```
f2 = Function[{x, y}, Evaluate[
    f[p, q] /. changeOfVariables
    ]];
f2[1, 2]
(* 7/2 *)
```

Comment: Recommend that you add a `Simplify`, i.e.,  `f[p, q] /. changeOfVariables // Simplify`